# glm rotating quaternion in Y axis deforms object

Tags: opengl, c++, glm

I'm implementing my own game engine in C++ and I need help here,

I have a game object, its orientation property is a quaternion and I want to rotate it A degrees in the Y axis.

So, I have:

```
currentAngle += 0.01; // currentAngle is a member variable, so yes i initialized it
quat q(currentAngle, vec3(0, 1, 0));
myGameObject->SetOrientation(q);

GameObject::SetOrientation(quat q)
{
 myOrientation  = q;
}
```

but as the game object rotates, it also gets scaled (deformed). So I checked how I am applying the transformation matrices

```
myModelMatrix = Math::CreateTransformationMatrix(
    transformation->GetPosition(),
    transformation->GetOrientation(), 
    transformation->GetScale()); 


mat4& Math::CreateTransformationMatrix(vec3&    translation, quat& orientation, vec3& scaleSize)
{

     mat4 translate = glm::translate(glm::mat4(), translation);
     mat4 rotate = glm::toMat4(orientation);
     mat4 scale = glm::scale(glm::mat4(), scaleSize);

    return  translate * rotate * scale;
}
```

but it looks ok (at least to me), I removed the scale matrix form the multiplication to check if somehow I was doing something with it. However, it didnt fix anything.

I also tried:

```
  quat q(currentAngle, vec3(0, 1, 0));
   quat orientation = myGameObject->GetOrientation();
   orientation  = orientation  *q;
   myGameObject->SetOrientation(orientation);
```

But it didnt work either.
I also checked the code in my shaders and I am positive is not the problem.

This is how I send the matrices to the shader:

```
glUseProgram(progarmId);1
    glUniformMatrix4fv(uniforms[name], 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(matrix));
```

I tried modifying the 3rd parameter to True and swapping the order of the projection view matrix multiplication and it didnt work either :/

So, guys ... any ideas what could I be doing wrong ? I'm out of ideas :/

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it is what's causing the problem but the CreateTransformationMatrix method should not return a reference type because the result is allocated on the stack in the scope of the method. So the resulting matrix is in an undefined state.